# Move left if there is a zero

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to create a program that will take an array of integers, say {2,0,32,0,0,8} that can be of any length, and make it so all of the nonzero numbers are to the left at the lower indexes, and all the zeros are moved to the end.
For example, {2,0,32,0,0,8} becomes {2,32,8,0,0,0}.
This array can be of any length and contain any nonnegative integers.
This is what I have so far:

```
public static int[] moveLeft(final int[] a) {
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       if (a[i] != 0) {
           for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
               if (a[j] == 0) {
                   a[j] = a[i];
                   a[i] = 0;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return a;
```

}

However, when I do this, it doesn't work for the first and second characters. If I have {1,2,0,1} it will return {2,1,1,0} when it should return {1,2,1,0}. Any help?

Comment: we can create an temp_array and add an element to it from original array only if it's non-zero. for zeroes, we can take an integer variable n_zeroes and initialize it to 0. increment it whenever there is a 0 element (instead of adding it to temp_array). Now, we can add zeroes, n_zeroes times at back of the temp_array. this temp_array is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop should stop before index `i`. Change this

```
for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
```

And then your code works for me.